# DDD (Domain-Driven-Design) - large aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm currently studying Eric Evans'es Domain-Driven-Design. The idea of aggregates is clear to me and I find it very interesting. Now I'm thinking of an example of aggregate like :

BankAccount (1) ----> (*) Transaction.

```
BankAccount
BigDecimal calculateTurnover();
```

BankAccount is an aggregate. To calculate turnover I should traverse all transactions and sum up all amounts. Evans assumes that I should use repositories to only load aggreagates. In the above case there could be a few tousands of transactions which I don't want load at once in memory.

> In the context of the repository pattern, aggregate roots are the only objects > your client code loads from the repository.
>
> The repository encapsulates access to child objects - from a caller's  perspective it automatically loads them, either at the same time the root is  loaded or when they're actually needed (as with lazy loading).

**What would be your suggestion to implement calulcateTurnover in a DDD aggregate ?**

Answer (score 6):

As you have pointed out, to load 1000s of entities in an aggregate is not a scalable solution.  Not only will you run into performance problems but you will likely also experience concurrency issues, as emphasised by Vaughn Vernon in his [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) series.

Do you want every transaction to be available in the `BankAccount` aggregate or are you only concerned with turnover?

If it is only the turnover that you need, then you should establish this value when instantiating your `BankAccount` aggregate. This could likely be effectively calculated by your data store technology (indexed JOINs, for example, if you are using SQL). Perhaps you also need to consider having this this as a precalculated value in your data store (what happens when you start dealing with millions of transactions per bank account)?

But perhaps you still require the transactions available in your domain?  Then you should consider having a separate `Transaction` repository.

I would highly recommend reading Vaughn Vernon's series on aggregate design, as linked above.

Comment: First of all - thanks for responding so quickly. I've ordered Vernon's book recently so I'll read it soon and come back to this thread.

Comment: Pleasure. Provided that you know the DDD basics and terminology, you could start off by reading that 3-part PDF series linked in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have managed to pick a very interesting example :)

I actually use `Account`1->*`Transaction` when explaining event sourcing (ES) to anyone not familiar with it.

As a developer I was taught (way back) to use what we can now refer to as entity interaction.  So we have a `Customer` record and it has a current state.  We change the state of the record in some way (address, tax details, discount, etc.) and store the result.  We never quite know what happened but we have the latest state and, since that is the current state of our business, it is just fine.  Of course one of the first issues we needed to deal with was concurrency but we had ways of handling that and even though not fantastic it "worked".

For some reason the accounting discipline didn't quite buy into this.  Why do we not simply have the latest state of an `Account`.  We will load the related record, change the balance, and save the state.  Oddly enough most people would probably cringe at the thought yet it seems to be OK for the rest of our data.

The accounting domain got around this by registering the change events as a series of `Transaction` entries.  So should you lose you account record and the latest balance you can always run though all the transactions to obtain the latest balance.  That is event sourcing.

In ES one typically loads an entire list of events for an aggregate root (AR) to obtain its latest state.  There is also, typically, a mechanism to deal with a huge number of events when loading all would cause performance issues: snapshots.  Usually only the latest snapshot is stored.  The snapshot contains the full latest state of the aggregate and only event after the snapshot version are applied.

One of the huge advantages of ES is that one could come up with new queries and then simply apply all the events to the query handler and determine the outcome.  Perhaps something like: "How many customer do I have that have moved twice in the last year".  Quite arbitrary but using the "traditional" approach the answer would quite likely be that we'll start gathering that information from today and have it available next year as we have not been saving the `CustomerMoved` events.  With ES we can search for the `CustomerMoved` events and get a result at any point.

So this brings me back to your example.  You probably do not want to be loading all the transactions.  Instead store the "Turnover" and calculate it on the go.  Should the "Turnover" be a new requirement then a once off processing of all the ARs should get it up to speed.  You can still have a `calculateTurnover()` method somewhere but that would be something you wouldn't run all too often.  And in those cases you would need to load all the transactions for an AR.